# Get Value from Bean in a List , JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf

I have a business scenario where I have to display the details of selected item in List.

```
<%System.out.print("Value : " + counterT); %>
<h:outputText value="#{search_rule_bean.dataTable[counterT].ruleName}"/>
```

I have to display the data of dataTable[counterT] bean object, Where counterT is the index of list. I am able to retrieve it from url request parameter. But is it not working for outputText whether it is working in SysOut.

Answer (score 0):

Process URL params similar to

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="counterT" value="#{search_rule_bean.counterT}"/> <!-- getter and setter required -->
```

and use it later like

```
<h:outputText value="#{search_rule_bean.dataTable[search_rule_bean.counterT].ruleName}"/>
```

Comment: From the data table as User select any row, I used to highlight it using through JS. At that time to save the value in bean I have used a inputHidden and set its value as follow: document.getElementById("form:hiddenInput").value = rowId;
But this value does not reflect in bean. I debug that but unable to find some solution

Comment: Is the hidden input field being processed? And have you tried my solution to process URL params?